sharpe ratio of 2 uncorrelated strategies
I was asked this question the other day:
By having two uncorrelated portfolios, one with sharpe ratio 2 and the other with sharpe ratio 5, what is the max sharpe ratio we can achieve.
I tried computing the sharpe ratio of the combined portfolio, where portfolio 1 was assigned a weight and portfolio 2 -> 1- weight and then compute the derivative with respect to w to get the optimal weight. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to be able to get a numeric result. If anyone knows how to solve this, I'd really appreciate it!
Thank you in advance!

Here is the numeric proof that a combination of the two assets will always get the same maximum Sharpe ratio (combined). I don't have the mathematical proof though:

On a side note, here is the mathematical formula: Optimise the Sharpe ratio of a portfolio of uncorrelated assets
